# Как переключить музыку python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux

Как переключить или поставить на паузу трек на python, linux?

Comment: Прочитать документацию к используемому вами музыкальному плееру и применить полученные знания на практике

Comment: @andreymal а если неизвестно в каком плеере играет трек...

Comment: Тогда никак, играть он может абсолютно где угодно и абсолютно кем угодно

Comment: @Masha если неизвестно какой плеер, то можно удалить звуковые драйвера из системы, это поставит музыку на паузу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ниже перевод

### Вопрос

[Вопрос на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62120276/pause-and-or-resume-audio-using-python-on-linux).

Я хочу ставить проигрываемую в фоне музыку на паузу и/или продолжать воспроизведение используя питон, нашёл такой вариант, который использует `pynput`:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, Key

c = Controller()
c.press(Key.media_play_pause)
```

Но аудио всё равно продолжает проигрываться. Похоже ошибок нет, но оно не работает.

### Ответ

[Ответ на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62121368/8489602).

Возможно тебе стоит попробовать [*playerctl*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62121368/8489602), утилита для командной строки, которую можно использовать через:

```
subprocess.call(("playerctl", "play-pause"))
```

Однако, playerctl возможно не установлена в твоей системе, то надо сделать сдедующее:

- `sudo apt install playerctl`,
- `pacman -Syu playerctl`,
- `sudo dnf install playerctl` or
- `sudo zypper install playerctl`

(в зависимости от дистрибутива)

Таким образом нет необходимости в `pynput`, вместо него `subprocess` (`import subprocess`). Если тебе не важны стиль и безопасность, ты можешь, конечно же, использовать `os.system("playerctl play-pause")`

Comment: Это сработает только если плеер поддерживает MPRIS, что верно не для всех плееров (а так как автор утверждает, что плеер неизвестен, то можно считать, что в общем случае этот ответ не подходит)

Comment: @andreymal Да, логично. Но оставим в ответах, кому то может и поможет.